# Do I need to zero-fill a qcow2 image before compacting it?

Tags: qcow2

I want to recreate a dynamically allocated qcow2 image in order to shrink it. Is it sufficient that all unnecessary files have been deleted, or do I also need to fill the space formerly occupied by those files with zeros? In other words, is qemu-img filesystem-aware?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you do need to zero-fill the filesystem if you want to recover the space used by deleted files.  And no, qemu-img isn't fs-aware.

I forgot to do this for one VM image I created today (a minimal Debian Sid image for my openstack cloud at work) and it ended up being almost 900MB, even with "-c" for qcow2 compression.

I recreated it after running "dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/zero ; rm -f /root/zero ; shutdown -h now", and the image size shrunk down to about 335MB.  That's a lot less (worthless) data to copy around whenever I start up a new instance.

there were a lot of deleted files, because the VM started out as debian squeeze and was apt-get upgraded to sid.

Answer (score 3):

See also: `virt-sparsify`, an utility which can zero-fill filesystems inside disk images (supporting various formats):

http://libguestfs.org/virt-sparsify.1.html

Answer (score 2):

I´m using zerofree ( `apt-get install zerofree` ) for this task:

> Zerofree finds the unallocated blocks with non-zero value content in 
>   an ext2, ext3 or ext4 file-system and fills them with zeroes

after that you can shrink your image:
`kvm-img convert -O qcow2 original_image.qcow2 deduplicated_image.qcow2`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it works better to clone the disk using Clonezilla or Symantec Ghost. It's a lot quicker than filling up the drive with zeros. Also it avoids the growing the image even more.

I have done this with Ghost and Win guests countless times. It's actually quicker if "used space" is smaller than those to be zeroed. Also you can use `qemu-nbd` to mount the images and run Clonezilla from host, avoiding the hassle of Clonezilla-within-guest. Either way it's always much quicker than `sdelete`/`dd` in my experience. (Also I often end up with no space available on host for a full zero-out-guest-disk operation, so filling up available space in guest in seldom feasible to me.)

Comment: Running Clonezilla or Ghost inside the VM ? Seems like a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I have done this with Ghost and Win guests countless times. It's actually quicker if "used space" is smaller than those to be zeroed. Also you can use `qemu-nbd` to mount the images and run Clonezilla from host. Either way it's always much quicker than `sdelete`/`dd` to me. (Also I often end up with no space available on host for a full zero-out-guest-disk operation.

Comment: Please add your comment to the answer to make it more substantive.

Answer (score 0):

Just to amplify on phoeagon's excellent suggestion which, I agree, is both quicker and better than [sdelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete).  The reason for this is that [e2image](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs), [ntfsclone](https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g) and [partclone](https://github.com/Thomas-Tsai/partclone) all have file system knowledge (partclone is the utility on which clonezilla is ultimately based). The whole disk is not scanned, only the files actually in use are saved to a new image.

The sdelete under Windows expands a sparse image to it's full size, and is super slow.  Zerofree under Linux on ext4 partitions does not expand disk images (but is still quite slow).

Here's an example session for cloning and shrinking a virtualbox `vdi` disk image to a qemu `qcow2` image on a Linux host.

These commands are done as root; **if done incorrectly, they could wipe your image file or your host!  Be very careful.**

For a `mbr` based windows 10 `vdi` image to qcow2 (to show two popular virtualisation formats).

```
#Check file system size
vboximg-mount -i "$(/bin/pwd)/win10.vdi" --list

#Create a (big) sparse qcow2 to accommodate the partitions found in
# the command above
qemu-img create -f qcow2 new.qcow2 300G

#Mount the vdi disk in ./mount with the
# VirtualBox mount utility.
#We don't mount the individual partitions in ./mount
vboximg-mount -i "$(/bin/pwd)/win10.vdi" --rw  mount

#Mount the disk new qcow2 image.
# connecting, in this instance, to /dev/nbd0
modprobe nbd max_part=16
qemu-nbd --connect /dev/nbd0 ./new.qcow2

#Change to the vdi mounted directory
cd mount

#Copy the mbr with the partition table
#./vhdd is the raw device.
#For EFI based boot systems, you'd be better to use
# sgdisk:
#   sgdisk --backup=../part_table.bin ./vhdd
#   sgdisk --load-backup=../part_table.bin /dev/nbd0
#   sgdisk -G /dev/nbd0
#But for mbr:
dd if=./vhdd of=/dev/nbd0 bs=512B count=1

#Check the image has our partition table and make sure it's
# device nodes have been setup by a kernel re-read.
fdisk /dev/nbd0
ls -la /dev/nbd0*
#vbox partitions are zero based (vol0,vol1,vol2); nbd based
# partitions start at 1 (nbd0p1,nbd0p2,nbd0p3).

#Copy the first partition properly with dd
#It's only 100MB.
dd if=./vol0 of=/dev/nbd0p1 bs=4M status=progress

#Copy the third partition properly with dd
dd if=./vol2 of=/dev/nbd0p3 bs=4M status=progress

#Use ntfsclone or partclone.ntfs to copy the main partition
partclone.ntfs -d -b -s ./vol1 -o /dev/nbd0p2

#Get out of the ./mount dir
cd ..

#Umount vdi
umount mount

#Disconnect the nbd device
qemu-nbd --disconnect /dev/nbd0
#Remove the module
sleep 2
rmmod nbd

mv new.qcow2 win10.qcow2
#Change the image to not be root
chown user_name: win10.qcow2
```

If you are new to all this, you will find that images swell to a given size (though usually less than the size from which they were originally reduced) because operating systems, especially windows, do create and delete a lot of temporary files.

Thanks once again to phoeagon for pointing me in this direction (I haven't got the rep to up-vote his answer).